# how to get total sum of database field value with where condition in laravel

Tags: laravel-4

I  table **student_atendence** table fields are (id ,studid,attendence).

This is my table **student_atendence**:

```
id   studid   attendence      
1    28            1     
2    31            0  
4    32            1   
5    28            0 
6    31            1   
7    32            1   
9    28            1   
10   31            1   
11   32            1   
13   28            1   
14   31            0   
15   32            1   
17   28            0   
18   31            1   
19   32            1   
21   28            1   
22   31            1   
23   32            0   
24   28            1   
25   31            1   
26   32            0
```

I want result like this

id   studid   total 1's  total 0's

```
1    28        6          1

2    31        6          1

3    32        5          2
```

how to get total count of attendence =1 and attendence=0 of each students separately.

Eg: 28 -  6 (total no.of 1 s) and 1(total o.of 0 s), 31 -  6 (total no.of 1 s) and 1(total o.of 0 s), 32 -  5 (total no.of 1 s) and 2(total o.of 0 s).

mycontroller code `foreach($students as $student){
            $cunt1 = DB::table($wys_attendence_table)
                        ->where('studid',$student->id)
                      ->where('amonth',$amonth)
                    ->where('ayear',$ayear)
                    ->where('attendence','=',1)
                     ->count();
           $cunt0 = DB::table($wys_attendence_table)
                     ->where('studid',$student->id)
                      ->where('amonth',$amonth)
                    ->where('ayear',$ayear)
                    ->where('attendence','=',0)
                     ->count();
                     //var_dump($cunt1);
                    //var_dump($cunt0);
            }`

my view page `@foreach($stud_attend as $stud_attends)
                                  @if($student->id == $stud_attends->studid)

                                      @if($stud_attends->attendence == 1)
                                  <td><font color="green" size="3">p</font></td>
                                      @elseif($stud_attends->attendence == 0)
                                  <td><font color="red" size="3">a</font></td>
                                      @endif
                                      <td>{{$cunt1}}</td>
                                  @endif
                              @endforeach`

i got the correct answer from var_dump($cunt0), var_dump($cunt1) but not work in view page..

how to change my code??

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
DB::table($wys_attendence_table)
->select(DB::raw('studid, sum(attendence = 1) AS `total1`, sum(attendence = 0) AS `total0`'))
->where('studid',$student->id)
->where('amonth',$amonth)
->where('ayear',$ayear);
```